# How to remove css class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to remove a css class using javascript in my rails form.

This is what I have so far. The goal is to reveal part of the form when the `drink` variable is Coffee.

Here's my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="field">
Drink: <%= f.select :drink, ["Coffee", "Orange Juice", "Tea"], id: 'extended_list' %><br />
</div>
<div id="js-coffee-type" class="d-none">Coffee Type: <%= f.select :coffee_type, ['Espresso', 'Cappuccino', 'Filter', 'Greek', 'Frappe', 'Latte'] %></div>

Sugar Amount: <%= f.select :sugar_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %><br />

Milk Amount: <%= f.select :milk_amount, ((1..5).map {|i| [i,i] } << ["None",nil]) %><br />
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "button is-info" %>
  <% end %>
    <style>
    .d-none { display: none; }
    </style>
  <script>
    $("#extended_list").change(function() {
      var drinks = $("#extended_list").val();
      if (drinks == "Coffee") {
        $(".js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none");
      } else {
        $(".js-coffee-type").addClass("d-none");
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. When you're selecting the `div` to remove the class `d-none you're using a class selector instead of an ID selector.

Change:

```
  if (drinks == "Coffee") {
    $(".js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none");
  } else {
    $(".js-coffee-type").addClass("d-none");
  }
```

To:

```
  if (drinks == "Coffee") {
    $('#js-coffee-type').removeClass('d-none');
  } else {
    $('#js-coffee-type').addClass('d-none');
  }
```

Comment: I realize that this is correct syntax, but i'm still unable to get the correct output. Is it possible i'm retrieving the value from the drink selection form incorrectly?

Comment: There could be a number of things going on. I think the simplest way to debug this would be to place a `debugger` within your `$("#extended_list").change` function. From there you can deduce whether 1) the right list is being selected 2) `var drinks` is being set correctly or 3) The class is being removed

Comment: What was the solution? Also if you can hit the checkmark to accept the answer if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in your code, your DOM selector should target your div using the id, like this:

```
$("#js-coffee-type").removeClass("d-none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an ID selector instead of a class selector. In addition, you may consider consolidating your conditional statement to the following:

```
$('#js-coffee-type').toggleClass('d-none', drinks == "Coffee");
```

As seen in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state), you may pass a second parameter for the `state` of the class, allowing you to control whether or not that class is to be enabled or disabled.